# How to extract data from a .tps topscan Clarion file?

Tags: clarion, tps

I have to make a MySQL database from a Clarion database. The tables are .tps files.

I don't know how to do it, for now I only found applications that work with .dat files.

Comment: I found one, even if you don't have Clarion.

Answer (score 11):

I made an open-source bulk [tps-to-csv](http://www.ctrl-alt-dev.nl/Projects/TPS-to-CSV/TPS-to-CSV.html) conversion utility.

Its based on [reverse engineering the TPS file format](http://blog.42.nl/articles/liberating-data-from-clarion-tps-files), so make sure you double check the results. The source (Java) can be found is available on github.

Comment: This probably only works on non-encrypted TPS files? Clarion-made EXE can have a symmetric crypto password embedded, then TPS files are different...

Comment: While blog posts mention encryption, the jar download page does not seem to listen command line option for the password...

Answer (score 3):

If you have a copy of Clarion, you should have the topscan.exe utility. It has an export feature.