# Convert from tps to csv

Tags: mysql, csv, clarion, tps

I am writing a program based on an SQL database to take the base of a Clarion 16 bit program which is soon to be non functional. However, I need to get their old records and the program does not offer much as far as export, and TopScan is like 600 dollars for a year. Is there any way for me to convert the .tps files they have to .csv? Before you start spitting out ideas here's what I've tried:

- Data Management Center (only lets me do the first 20 and also like 600 dollars)
- tpsUtil (returns `database must start with lm=` however I can't modify database)
- DBFView (lied, can't handle TPS files)
- Clarion Conversion Assistant (only generates the code necessary to convert with Clarion, this still requires I buy TopSpeed)

If you know how to convert TPS to CSV you will be my hero...

Comment: Do you have any info on the `.tps` format?

Comment: i didnt even know there was multiple formats it could be in i have never worked with clarion im just trying to extract the data

Comment: have you tried TopScan ODBC Driver(http://www.softvelocity.com/Drivers/TSODBC.htm) you may also be interested in this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930268/how-to-extract-data-from-a-tps-topscan-clarion-file and the utility mentioned http://www.ctrl-alt-dev.nl/Projects/TPS-to-CSV/TPS-to-CSV.html.

Comment: bansi your a genius i wish i could upvote your comment can i answer my own question with in depth tutorial

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Faced with a similar situation last year I reverse engineered the Clarion TPS file format and wrote a utility to do the conversion to proper CSV.

Its called [tps-to-csv](http://www.ctrl-alt-dev.nl/Projects/TPS-to-CSV/TPS-to-CSV.html). It's (open) source code is on [github](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-dev/tps-parse)

I hope you find it useful, but please do check the results and report any inconsistencies.